# An unhandled exception was thrown by the application

Tags: python, django

I've created my new site using DjANGO

AT FIRST Everything is okay startapp,syncdb......Etc

but the problems its this massage

Unhandled Exception
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

you can see 
http://www.daqiqten.com/

this is my index.fsgi and .htacces

```
index.fcgi
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path. (optional)
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/daq")

# Switch to the directory of your project.
os.chdir("/home/daq/newproject")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "newproject.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")


___________

.htacces
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 'DEBUG' turned on in your app's settings? Maybe you will get some more information about the Exception that was raised.

Comment: Good advice. Tell us what you find out!